# Populate a select box with user names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my view I have a form with a select

```
    <%= label_tag("employee_names", "Employees") %>
    <%= select_tag("employee_names", params[:employee_names]) %>
```

And then I have a bunch of users, these users have a name `user.name` and an id `user.id`.

I have a method in the controller that when given the user id, narrows my list down to a specific users objects.

```
    if params[:employee_names].present?
      @time_sheets = @time_sheets.joins(:user).where("users.id IN (?)", params[:employee_names])
    end
```

So what I am having an issue with, is I am not sure how to populate my select box with a list of users names. And then when submitted I need it to give the users id to that method. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think `options_from_collection_for_select` should do the trick for you.

More here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select

```
select_tag :employees, options_from_collection_for_select(@employees, 'id', 'name')
```

Comment: I am getting a "undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass" error, not sure what's causing it

Comment: What does your entire form look like?

Comment: Where do you get "employee_names" from?  Can you post the relevant code from the controller?  You have to update the above options_from_collection_for_select to use a collection w/ user names and ids.

Comment: <%= form_tag({}, class: "form-inline") do %>
 <%= label_tag("employee_names", "Employees") %>
 <%= collection_select(:employee, :employee_id, @timesheets, :id, 'Employees') %>
 <%= label_tag("start_date", "Start Date") %>
 <%= text_field_tag("start_date", params[:start_date], placeholder: "yyyy-mm-dd") %>
 <%= label_tag("end_date", "Start Date") %>
 <%= text_field_tag("end_date", params[:end_date], placeholder: "yyyy-mm-dd") %>
 <%= submit_tag("Filter Hours") %>
  <% end %> **And I picked employee_names arbitrarily, the only code from the controller is what i posted above**

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select).

```
<%= collection_select(:employee, :employee_id, @time_sheets, :id, 'Employees') %>
```

Comment: I am getting a "undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass" error, not sure what's causing it

Comment: I had misspelled your @time_sheets instance variable. I didn't include the underscore. Try it now.